# Lipschitz continuity of a generalized Rayleigh quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, continuity

I am thinking about the Lipschitz continuity of a generalized Rayleigh quotient: $f(x)=\frac{x^\top Ax}{x^\top Bx}$ with the constraint $||x||\geq c$, where both $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices, $c$ is some positive constant, and I have the following questions:

1. If $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous with respect to $\ell_2$ ($\ell_1$) norm?
2. If so, how to compute the Lipschitz constant $L$?

It seems that it's difficult to compute $L$ directly using the definition of Lipschitz constant. I read somewhere that if $f(x)$ is convex, then $L\geq ||z||_*$ for all $x$, where $z$ is the gradient of $f(x)$: $z=\nabla f(x)$, and $||z||_*$ is the dual norm of $z$ (For $\ell_2$ norm, $||z||_*=||z||$.) .

So I am wondering if I can compute  $L$ by $L=\sup \{\nabla  f(x) ：  \nabla f(x)=\frac{2Ax(x^\top Bx)-2x^\top AxBx}{(x^\top Bx)^2}\}$ ?

Even though it's true, I don't know what to do next step. How can I prove if $||\nabla f(x)||_*$ is bounded and how to compute its upper bound?

In addition, we know that a generalized Rayleigh quotient is not convex, can we still use $||\nabla f(x)||_*$ to compute its Lipschitz constant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is homogeneous of degree zero: $f(tx)=f(x)$ for all $t>0$. This implies that its gradient (with respect to whatever norm) is homogeneous of degree $-1$, that is $\nabla f(tx)=t^{-1}\nabla f(x)$ for all $t>0$.

The gradient is bounded on every set of the form $\{x:\|x\|\ge r\}$ with $r>0$. Indeed, it is bounded on the unit sphere by some constant $M$ (by continuity and   compactness), hence bounded by $M/r$ on the aforementioned set.

One can estimate $M$ (the supremum of the gradient on the unit sphere) as follows: 
$$\|\nabla f(x)\| \le 
\left\|\frac{2Ax }{x^\top Bx}\right\|+
\left\| \frac{2x^\top AxBx}{(x^\top Bx)^2}\right\|\le 2\|A\|\,\|B^{-1}\|+2\|A\|\,\|B\|\,\|B^{-1}\|^2$$

In a convex domain, the supremum of the gradient equals the Lipschitz constant. The set $\{x:\|x\|\ge r\}$ is not convex, but it is *quasiconvex*, namely:  any two points $a,b$ can be joined by a curve $\gamma$ of length at most $\frac{\pi}{2}|a-b|$ (an arc of a circle will do). Integrating the gradient along such a curve gives a bound for the Lipschitz constant: 
$$
|f(a)-f(b)|\le \int_\gamma \|\nabla f\| \le \frac{\pi}{2}|a-b|\sup\|\nabla f\|
$$
Hence $L\le \frac{\pi}{2}\sup\|\nabla f\|$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that, @Behaviour. I omitted a constraint: $||x||\leq c$.

Comment: That does not help because the gradient blows up near the origin. If you had $\|x\|\ge c$, the function   would be Lipschitz there.

Comment: Yes. It should be $||x||\geq c$... Given this constraint, how can we compute the Lipschitz constant $L$?

Comment: I guess I can just let the constraint be $||x||=c$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the supremum on $\|x\|=c $ is the supremum on $\|x\|\ge 1$. Also, you might as well take $c=1$ in the calculation instead of carrying it around; it contributes the factor of $1/c$ to the final result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Behaviour! Could you please explain more about the inequality? Should the first inequality be $$\|\nabla f(x)\| \le 
\left\|\frac{2Ax }{x^\top Bx}\right\|+
\left\| \frac{2x^\top AxBx}{(x^\top Bx)^2}\right\|  $$ rather than $\|\nabla f(x)\| \le 
\left\|\frac{2Ax }{(x^\top Bx)^2}\right\|+
\left\| \frac{2x^\top AxBx}{(x^\top Bx)^2}\right\|$?

Comment: Also, I read somewhere that the generalized Rayleigh quotient $f(x)$ itself is not convex. Can we still bound the Lipschitz constant in this way?

Comment: I corrected the denominator. Convexity is not needed to estimate $f(a)-f(b)$ by integrating $\nabla f$; this is just the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals.

Comment: Thanks @Behaviour. Your answer really helps!

Comment: Hi @Behaviour, I studied line integral these days, but I still cannot figure out why the inequality $|f(a)-f(b)|\leq  \int_\gamma || \nabla f||$ holds. Because $\nabla f$ is the gradient (therefore vector), we cannot apply mean value theorem for this line integral, and we cannot bound the integral by the norm of $\nabla f$